# Unwanted pornographic spam

Tags: gmail

I have been inundated with unsolicited sexual spam in my Junk Mail.  It started a few weeks ago.  I have tried to “unsubscribe” but most of it doesn’t have a way to do that or the unsubscribe email bounces back as undeliverable.

The only thing that I can possibly link it to is a retaliation for writing negative reviews about a slots game I play.  The reason I think this is that there are “Casino” spam emails interspersed with the sexually explicit ones.

I have never opened any of the spam emails.  I am deleting them constantly.  Unfortunately, at times, it isn’t unusual to get 10 in an hour.

I am hopeful you can assist me with this problem.

Comment: Gmail has a Spam label. The term "Junk Mail" is used by Outlook and perhaps other email services. Are you using Gmail? If so, are you using it directly on a web browser or are you using an installable email client? What is the problem of having such emails on the spam/Junk Mail?

Comment: Whatever you do, never, *ever*, attempt to "unsubscribe" from spam.  What you are really doing is notifying the spammers that you opened their email.  They will put you on a higher priority "spam even more" list since they now know they are getting through to you.  Also make sure you never load images in spam as that will also notify them.

Answer (score 0):

your options are as follows:

- by selecting email you can **mute** it or label it as **spam**

[image]

- by opening the email you can further **block** it or **report** it

[image]

- if you are heavily targeted you can **send feedback** to Gmail support

[image]

- also, if those emails are already in your spam folder you can ignore it - it gets auto-deleted after 30 days

[image]

**note that it's unwise to unsubscribe from spam emails**

Answer (score 0):

Supplement to the helpful answer from MARK:

You can define a filter that puts all incoming messages containing certain common spam words directly into a homemade spam folder (label), skipping the inbox.

Then if you find out you didn't get an important message from someone, you could force yourself to take a look in that folder to see if it inadvertently landed there.  Otherwise, you could happily ignore that folder forever.

Also: have you changed your password?  That might help, if the other person has figured out your password and is simply logging into your account.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, unsubscribing doesn't work and makes the situation worse because you are telling the spammer that the email address is active, and if unsubscribing sends you to a website, they could be getting more personal information, and your location (through IP address).